# Fill vector using function specified by enum

Tags: c++, enums, lambda, factory

The functionality that I want is like:

```
std::vector<float> GetFuncVec(int N, FuncType type)
{
    std::vector<float> fn(N);
    float tmp = (N - 1) / 2.0;

    switch (type) {
    case SIN:
        for (int i=0; i<N; ++i)
            fn[i] = sin(M_PI * i / tmp);
        break;
    case SINC:
        for (int i=0; i<N; ++i)
            fn[i] = sin(M_PI * i / tmp) / (M_PI * i / tmp);
        break;
    ...
    }

    return fn;
}
```

I find this unsatisfactory because there is a lot of code duplication. Looking around, I found the STL algorithm [`std::generate()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/generate/) which can fill a vector using a functor, which can have an increment member to play the role of `i`.

I see two potential routes. The first is to use a factory to initialize the functor. The problem with this method is code separation (above, the different cases are kept nicely together) and increased overheads with multiple new classes needed.

The second is to use lambda functions (which I have very little experience with). This is nice because I can define each function in a single line in the switch statement. But I don't see how I can avoid a scoping problem (the lambda function is not accessible outside the scope of the switch statement).

Is there a solution using lambda functions? What is the best option, from an efficiency viewpoint and from a readability viewpoint?

Comment: *"the lambda function is not accessible outside the scope of the switch statement"* -- Why wouldn't it be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you want something like this...?  (see it run [here](http://ideone.com/q3bX7V)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <functional>

enum Func { Sin, Sinc };

std::vector<float> f(int n, Func func)
{
    std::vector<float> results(n);
    float tmp = (n - 1) / 2.0;
    int i;
    std::function<float()> fns[] = {
        [&] { return sin(M_PI * i / tmp); },
        [&] { return sin(M_PI * i / tmp) / (M_PI * i / tmp); }
    };
    auto& fn = fns[func];
    for (i=0; i<n; ++i)
        results[i] = fn();

    return results;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<float> x = f(10, Sin);
    for (auto& v : x) std::cout << v << ' '; std::cout << '\n';

    std::vector<float> y = f(10, Sinc);
    for (auto& v : y) std::cout << v << ' '; std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
0 0.642788 0.984808 0.866025 0.34202 -0.34202 -0.866025 -0.984808 -0.642788 -2.44929e-16 
-nan 0.920725 0.705317 0.413497 0.122477 -0.0979816 -0.206748 -0.201519 -0.115091 -3.89817e-17
```

Comment: This has the advantage of being enclosed in a single function `f()`. However, I would prefer to use the enums when defining each function, in case the ordering changes. This should be a matter of including a `Func::NFuncs` enum, right?

Comment: Yes - `NFuncs` is a reasonable compile time way to size `fns[]`, then you have to make sure you don't forget to insert one of the elements.  BTW /- if your calling code is always hard-coding one of the functions, you can have `template <Func func> f()` and not need the array at all, then invoke ala `auto x = f<Sin>(10);`... very likely faster and more reliable, but I guess you knew that anyway and it's not your usage scanerio....

Comment: Right. I'd like to keep the ability to configure the function at runtime. Thanks though.

Comment: @DavidHall Was just thinking... you could have `std::pair<Func,std::function<float()>> = { { Sin, [&] { ... } }, { Sinc, [&] ... } };` - then an iteration over `fns` could check the indices are incrementing... proves order hasn't changed (would be runtime though) - combined with `NFuncs` you can also check you haven't missed any.

Answer (score 1):

One option that may not be fast (there is indirection on each function call) but that would be a bit more flexible would be to create an `std::map<FuncType, std::function<float(int,float)>>`.  You can't use `std::generate()` because you need the argument `i` to calculate the result, but writing your own is not that hard:

```
template <typename Iterator, typename Generator, typename Index, typename... Args>
void generate_i(Iterator first, Iterator last, Generator gen, Index i, Args... args)
{
    while (first != last) {
        *first = gen(i, args...);
        ++i;
        ++first;
    }
}
```

Now that we have this, we need to populate a map of functors:

```
using FuncTypeFunction = std::function<float(int,float)>;
using FuncTypeFunctionMap = std::map<FuncType, FuncTypeFunction>;

FuncTypeFunctionMap create_functype_map()
{
    FuncTypeFunctionMap functions;

    functions[SIN]  = [] (int i, float tmp) {
        return sin(M_PI * i / tmp);
    };

    functions[SINC] = [] (int i, float tmp) {
        return sin(M_PI * i / tmp) / (M_PI * i / tmp);
    };

    // ...

    return functions;
}

FuncTypeFunctionMap const FuncTypeFunctions = create_functype_map();
```

(If you prefer you can use boost.assign to improve readability of this bit.)

And finally, we can use this map:

```
std::vector<float> GetFuncVec(int N, FuncType type)
{
    std::vector<float> fn(N);
    float tmp = (N - 1) / 2.0;

    auto func = FuncTypeFunctions.find(type);
    if (func != FuncTypeFunctions.end()) {
        generate_i(fn.begin(), fn.end(), func->second, 0, tmp);
    }

    return fn;
}
```

Adding new functions only requires populating the map in `create_functype_map()`.  Note that each iteration in the `generate_i()` loop is going to invoke the `operator()` on `std::function`, which will require a level of indirection to resolve the call, similar to the overhead of a virtual method invocation.  This will cost a bit in terms of performance but may not be an issue for you.

([See a demo](http://ideone.com/9EynHp))

Comment: It should be possible to calculate the `Index i` parameter on-the-fly, within `generate_i()`, right? Then I think you've created something which should go in the STL :-)

Comment: @DavidHall The value of `i` is incremented in the body of `generate_i()`. I exposed the `i` parameter to make the function even more general -- you can start an indexes other than zero, for example.

Answer (score 1):

You may write a general class that will be used in standard algorithm `std::iota`

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>

class Value
{
public:
    Value() : i( 0 ), fn( []( size_t i ) { return ( float )i; } ) {}
    Value & operator ++() { ++i; return *this; }
    operator float () const { return fn( i ); }
    Value & operator =( std::function<float( size_t )> fn )
    {
        this->fn = fn;
        return *this;
    }
private:
    size_t i;
    std::function<float( size_t )> fn;
};


enum E { First, Second };

std::vector<float> f( size_t N, E e )
{

    Value value;

    float tmp = N / 2.0f;

    switch( e )
    {
    case First:
        value = [tmp] ( size_t i ) { return i * tmp; };
        break;

    case Second:
        value = [tmp] ( size_t i ) { return i * tmp + tmp; };
        break;
    }

    std::vector<float> v( N );

    std::iota( v.begin(), v.end(), value );

    return v;
}

int main() 
{
    for ( float x : f( 10, First ) ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    for ( float x : f( 10, Second ) ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
0 5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 
5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 50
```

Of course you may use your own lambda expressions that include some mathematical functions like `sin`

Comment: This is actually much closer to the syntax that I was originally expecting. I'll have to consider which of the 3 answers is best.